# Fiving entry point for procedure sqlite3_open_v2 cannot be found in dynamic link library sqlite3.dll

Tags: qgis, installation

I have a problem installing version 1.0.8. The following error message appears:

> The entry point for the procedure `sqlite3_open_v2` cannot be found in the dynamic link library `sqlite3.dll`

*[The next sentence is ungrammatical in the original and therefore its translation is in doubt.]*

Previously I had version 1.7 Wroclaw, which I uninstalled before installing the new one.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're referring to qgis 1.8

A quick google search pointed me on [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/ERROR-The-procedure-entry-point-sqlite3-open-v2-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-sqln-tp4981789p4984540.html):

> Manually copying sqlite.dll from C:\osgeo4w\bin to C:\osgeo4w\apps\qgis\bin DID SOLVE my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I renamed file sqlite3.dll of (system folder) c:\windows\system32\ folder to something like renamed_sqlite3.dll. It solved the problem. But it might cause other errors but till now its working fine. You can restore the renamed file at any time if other applications get issues.