# qgis-bin.exe - Entry Point Not Found (QGIS 2.4 / 2.5)

Tags: qgis-2

Since upgrading to QGIS 2.4 (Chugiak) I have been receiving the below pop-up error...

*qgis-bin.exe - Entry Point Not Found
The procedure entry point xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt could not be
located in the dynamic link library C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\spatialite.dll*

I have tried multiple re-installs, once with the bare minimum of software and libraries, but continue to get the same error. The required dll file IS in the bin folder and exists no where else on the system (I've read that should the dll exists ion the system32 folder it will act as the default and throw a wrench into the functioning of any dependant software).

I have also adapted the solution at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30450/12354, but to no avail.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try the 32-bit installer of OSGEO4W, or QGIS standalone. I did not get such an error message recently.

By the way, current version is now QGIS 2.6.